# clojure and ring: utf-8 in responses comes through as '?'

Tags: utf-8, clojure, ring

I was surprised to find my ring app was not serving utf-8 properly.  I pared this down to a simple test case, does anyone know how to ensure that this will always return utf-8 to the browser?

```
(ns utf8test.core)

(defn app
  [request]
  {:status 200 :body "ɮѪϴ"})
```

In project.clj (using the lein-ring plugin):

```
:ring {:handler utf8test.core/app}
```

In terminal:

```
> lein ring server
```

---> É®ÑªÏ´   (this is wrong, should be ɮѪϴ)

Preferably a method that works for tomcat as well, since this is where the app is being deployed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without setting a `Content-Type` header, Jetty is probably sending a response indicating the platform-default encoding.  Try using the [`content-type` or `charset`](https://github.com/mmcgrana/ring/blob/master/ring-core/src/ring/util/response.clj#L130) response functions to add an appropriate header (e.g. `(charset {:status 200 :body "..."} "UTF-8")`).